# c++: размещение в stl контейнера потомков класса

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, stl, контейнеры

Подскажите, есть ли возможность хранить в STL контейнере потомков некоторого класса (с сохранением всех значений членов потомков)?

```
class CBase
{
public:
    char z = 'x';
};

class CChild1 : public CBase
{
public:
    int m_x;

    CChild1(const int x) { m_x = 1; };
};

class CChild2 : public CBase
{
public:
    double m_y;
    CChild2(const double y) { m_y = y; };
};

std::vector<CBase> storage;

storage.push_back(CChild1(2));
storage.push_back(CChild2(3.45));
```

Никакой ошибки компилятор не выдает, но в контейнере хранится похоже уже не то, что я в него закладывал :(

Подскажите, можно ли вообще решить эту проблему?

Я понимаю, что проблема решается просто через `std::vector<CBase*>`, но для этого мне надо создавать сначала объект, а потом передавать на него указатель, это не очень красиво, надо заморачиваться с хранением объектов и т.д., вот и подумалось, можно ли этого избежать?

Сами по себе классы CChild1 и Child2 могут очень сильно отличаться, вплоть до разных методов.

Comment: Через указатели (обычные или интеллектуальные), или через ссылки - с использованием соответствующего класса-оболочки, так как ссылки непосредственно хранить нельзя. А иначе - *срезка*...

Comment: Вы ясно сказали языку, что в вашем контейнере хранятся объекты типа `CBase`. Это значит, что там хранятся именно объекты типа `CBase`. Объекты никаких других типов в этом контейнере храниться не могут.

Comment: как вариант еще конверт-письмо

Comment: Или напишите класс, который хранит ссыльку на   CBase ... и заполняйте вектор обьектами этого класса

Comment: Рекомендую использовать бустовскую Pointer Container Library https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html Там владение настраивается, оператор [] ссылку возвращает, а не указатель, и еще удобные детали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с контейнерами полиморфных объектов общепринятым подходом является использование умных указателей (smart pointers) в качестве хранимых элементов. В простых случаях (это 90% случаев) будет достаточно [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
using MyVector = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CBase>>;

MyVector storage;
storage.emplace_back(std::make_unique<CChild1>(2));
storage.emplace_back(std::make_unique<CChild2>(3.45));
```

`std::unique_ptr` практически не добавляет оверхеда, может быть использован полиморфно (член-функция `get()` или `operator*` вернут сырой указатель или ссылку на `CBase` соответственно), а также сам заботится о времени жизни объекта, указатель на который содержит.

> Сами по себе классы CChild1 и Child2 могут очень сильно отличаться, вплоть до разных методов.

Это уже выглядит подозрительным. Если базовый класс не предоставляет достаточный интерфейс, то без явного приведения `CBase -> CChild` через `dynamic_cast` или `static_cast` в точке использования не обойтись, а это может быть признаком неудачного дизайна.